Live preview as you type with prompt_toolkit
I would like to have a repl with a live preview that shows the result as you type. For example
3
> 1 + 2

error
> 1 + 2 +

6
> 1 + 2 + 3

Is there an easy way to achieve this?
I saw https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/full_screen_apps.html
but it seems like it would just be easier to do this with ANSI escape codes by hand.
